# Поиск назад в регулярном выражении JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:
`=СУММ(A18:I18)`

Нужно написать регулярное выражение где производился бы поиск всех цифр `18` в строке, кроме тех, у которых перед `18` есть буква `A`.

Пишу `/(?<=A)+18/g` - выдаёт ошибку  Недопустимый квантификатор `?`.

Comment: лишний `+` в регулярном выражении. Плюс сейчас выводятся как раз 18 которые после `A`.

Comment: А не проще написать так: `/[^A](18)/g` ?

Comment: @And, для чего вы обернули 18 в отдельную группу?

Comment: `/(?<![A\d])18(?!\d)/g` ?

Comment: в js почему-то ?<! не работает((((

Comment: @ЯрославРаботаТолстой, потому что в спецификацию look behind только недавно добавили, еще не все браузеры реализовали

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, в случае, если там будет например `(\d+)`. И нужно будет вытащить `n` сумму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Chrome и любой другой среде, поддерживающей стандарт ECMA2018, можно воспользоваться блоком предварительного просмотра назад:

```js
console.log("=СУММ(A18:I18)".match(/(?<![A\d])18(?!\d)/g))
console.log("=СУММ(A18:I18)".replace(/(?<![A\d])18(?!\d)/g, "<ТУТ>$&</ТУТ>"))
```

**Подробности**

- `(?<![A\d])` - сразу перед `18` не должно быть `A` или цифры
- `18` - `18`
- `(?!\d)` - сразу после `18` не должно быть цифры

В других случаях придётся решить проблему с помощью захватывающих групп:

```js
var s = "=СУММ(A18:I18)";
var rx = /([A\d])?18(?!\d)/g;
console.log(s.replace(rx, function ($0, $1) { return $1 ? $0 : "<ТУТ>" + $0 + "</ТУТ>" }))
```

Тут `([A\d])?` — необязательная захватывающая группа, она находит `A` или цифру. Если этот шаблон захватывает текст, буфер группы №1 непустой  и в таком случае совпадение `18` является валидным. Если проверка первой группы не проходит успешно, совпадение считается не найденным.