# Замена строк регулярным выражением в JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:
СЧЁТЕСЛИМН('ИСХ_Сделки'!$B:$B;C$3;'ИСХ_Сделки'!$J:$J;$A18)СУММ(C18:I18)AK18+AT18+AB18+S18+J18СУММ(U18:AA18)
На выходе нужно получить:
СЧЁТЕСЛИМН('ИСХ_Сделки'!$B:$B;C$3;'ИСХ_Сделки'!$J:$J;$A18)СУММ(C122:I122)AK122+AT122+AB122+S122+J122СУММ(U122:AA122)

Что писать в регулярном выражении?
`var resultValue = "СЧЁТЕСЛИМН('ИСХ_Сделки'!$B:$B;C$3;'ИСХ_Сделки'!$J:$J;$A18)СУММ(C18:I18)AK18+AT18+AB18+S18+J18СУММ(U18:AA18)";`
Пишу

```
alert(resultValue.replace(new RegExp("A18",'g'),"A122"));
```

Меняет только A18 на A122.

Comment: Вы написали в `replace` - *поменять  A18 на A122*. Какой результат вы ожидали?

Comment: Чёрт, логично))))) А как правильно было бы действовать в данном случае?

Comment: Смотря, что вы хотите сделать!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поиск назад в регулярном выражении JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891657/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-js)

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/891701/182013), если это не то, что надо, оставьте там комментарий. Не нужно задавать несколько вопросов по одной и той же проблеме.